# Meta-boxes on my plugin's options page

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I've created a small wordpress plugin which has a settings-page in the backend (created via `add_options_page()`), which loads the contents of a file named 'admin.php' (located in the directory of the plugin).

What do I need to put in 'admin.php' to show some meta-boxes? (I've already tried `add_meta_box()`, but I can't get it working).

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is your function hooked into the `add_meta_boxes` action?

Comment: You'd better do it by hand. Style [reference](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved now! I just registered the meta-box to the context "normal", but in do_beta_boxes i used "side". So i changed "side" in do_meta_boxes to "normal" - problem solved.

**But now I'm having a different problem:**
The meta-boxes can't be toggled. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please add meta-boxes as per describe in below link may useful for you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: I know how to use them. But it just wont work (because i need to use them on my new created options-page).

Comment: What code you used ? please give me more description.